How can I incorporate a switching parameter value (like a telegraph process) in a coupled SDE?
I have a coupled 2D Langevin Equation:
$$dx(t)/dt = v(t)\cos(\phi(t)) + \sigma_t \, \text{noise}_{1x}(t), $$
$$dy(t)/dt = v(t)\sin(\phi(t)) + \sigma_t \, \text{noise}_{1y}(t), $$
$$d\phi(t)/dt = \sigma_r \, \text{noise}_{2}(t), $$
where $v(t)$ switches between an on (with magnitude $s$) and off-state (resting) i.e., $v: 0  \to s$ with rate $\alpha$, and $s \to 0$  with rate $\beta$ (telegraph process with $\alpha, \beta$ transition rates).
I wrote a code to model the equations (without the switching condition in the velocity) which is as follows:
Module[{t, x, y, ϕ, w1, w2, w3, 
  v0 = 0.1, σr = 1, σt = 1},
 proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
     v0*Cos[ϕ[t]] \[DifferentialD]t +  σt \[DifferentialD]w1[
         t], \[DifferentialD]y[t] == v0*Sin[ϕ[
         t]] \[DifferentialD]t +  σt \[DifferentialD]w2[
         t], \[DifferentialD]ϕ[t] == σr \[DifferentialD]w3[t]}, {x[t], 
    y[t], ϕ[t]}, {{x, y, ϕ}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   t, {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1], 
    w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1], 
    w3 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1]}];
 sol = RandomFunction[proc , {0, 1000, 0.1}, 10];
 ]
ListLinePlot[sol["Components"][[#]]] & /@ Range[10]

How can I implement the time-dependent switching probability for the velocity, $v(t)$, and evolve the equations?
